# NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MealTableViewCell - must register a nib

Tags: swift, nib

I was doing the apple guide for **Swift**, and I came across an error saying:

```
 "NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a
  cell with identifier MealTableViewCell - must register a nib or 
  a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard".
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on your cell and go to the attributes inspector and see if you have given the cell the reuse identifier `MealTableViewCell` like this

[image]

Comment: Should I still leave MealTableViewCell in the Class box of the cell?

Comment: Not the class box. Look at the image I posted. You will be able to enter the class in the 3rd tab. Click on the 4th tab and you'll see a field as Identifier with the placeholder text `Reuse Identifier`. Enter the identifier there and the problem you're having should be resolved. Let me know if it's still not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was so useful! I was always putting it Identifier under identity!